# K-Theory of $C(X)$ for $X$ not totally disconnected

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

My question is related to [K-Theory of $C(X)$ for $X$ totally disconnected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250301/k-theory-of-cx-for-x-totally-disconnected)

**Question:**
Does anyone know an example of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ (that is not totally disconnected) where $K_0(C(X))$ is not isomorphic to $C(X,\mathbb{Z})$?

I made the blunder of "proving" injectivity with the following faulty argument: the dimension map $\mathrm{dim}$ on $P_n(C(X))=\{p\in M_n(C(X)):p=p^*=p^2\}$ satisfies $$\mathrm{dim}\thinspace p = 0 \iff p=0_n$$
Therefore injectivity holds. The reason this argument fails is because the kernel being trivial implies injectivity for groups (not monoids)---$P_\infty(C(X))=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}P_n(C(X))$ is a monoid with binary operation $\oplus$ which I forgo defining.

I am new to K-Theory, but please feel free to be candid. There must be some sensitivity to the parameter $x\in X$ since $K_0(C(\{x\}))\cong K_0(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{Z}\cong C(\{x\},\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753575/k-0c-mathbbtn-cong-mathbbz2n-1/3753637#3753637).